# IIS - How to create local site on specific port and without sitename in URL

Tags: iis

Is is possible to create a local site on IIS that is served on the URL http://localhost:pppp/ or http://x.x.x.x/pppp instead of the default URL http://localhost/MySiteName?

I've followed a few MSDN articles ([1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1zz9df4.aspx),[2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis)) which result in the second URL which includes the sitename but I want to have the format of the first URL i.e. specify a specific port and omit the sitename.

NOTE: in my case I am using IIS version 10 on Windows 10.

UPDATE: I will try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758360/change-iis-domain-url) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `localhost` is always relative. On your own PC, `localhost` will resolve to your PC. From any other PC, `localhost` will not send the request to your PC, but to it's own. This is relevant if you want to serve the sites to other computers besides your own.

There is quite alot of information missing from your question, in terms of what goals you are trying to achieve, so all this information might not be relevant.

To create a site that will respond to `http://x.x.x.x:pppp/`, simply add a new site (or edit a pre-existing one) and set the binding (`Actions` on the right hand site > `Bindings`) to whichever port you want it to be. Here you can also add a hostname if you want plan to use SNI with multiple sites on the same IP and PORT.

**General tips:**

- Don't use a commonly used port if you're unsure (often used by other services. Your are mostly safe on 1024+).
- If you want other computers on your LAN to be able to access the site using a name instead of your IP, you need a local DNS service that the clients will need to use.
- If you want the site to be available from the Internet using a name instead of IP, you'll need to buy a domain name, and possible look into port forwarding on your firewall/router
- Don't forget to make the appropriate changes to your Windows Firewall once you have chosen which port the site is going to run from.